# setting a value based on a condition on environment variable as a number in github action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to set a value based on a condition whether an environment variable is bigger than x.

Something like:

```yaml
steps:
  ... setting env.COVERAGE
  - name: create badge
    with:
      ... 
      color: ${{ env.COVERAGE > 90 && 'green' || 'red' }}
```

I understand how to set a value on condition (`${{ condition && ifTrue || ifFalse }}`) but did not manage to use the value as a number.

How can I do that?

Comment: Seems that [Expressions don’t support ternary operators](https://github.community/t/do-expressions-support-ternary-operators-to-change-their-returned-value/18114). You could check the thread for some solutions like `${{ fromJSON('["green", "red"]')[env.COVERAGE > 90] }}` could work for you